# What does 'my behavior went skyrocket' mean here?

Tags: sentence

I told a guy about how my relationship with my parents improved after I apologized for my behavior and my actions. He replied, "I also experienced something like this. My behavior and attitude towards my parents went skyrocket last month."

What does that reply mean?

Thank you.

Comment: It means whatever the person who said it wanted it to mean. There is a general common sense that it means it won't be normal or usual behaviour. In fact, it would be extremely far from usual, whether good, bad, manic. Probably manic.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I just had confusion whether he's saying that in a positive sense or a negative sense.

Comment: When students' behaviour goes skyrocket, it is probably good from the view of the students, and bad from the view of the teachers. Relativity.

Comment: I would take it to mean that he’s acknowledging your improved relationship and saying “me too- only more”. Your just improved, mine skyrocketed. Yours want just recent mine want last month.